# How can I change size and color of clicked value at DateCalender MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am tring to change size and color of  clicked value at DateCalender MUI, and the Below is part of my code.

```
const Calendars = ({state}: {state: StateData;}) => {

const CustomDateCalendar = styled(DateCalendar)`
    .MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root {
    display: none;
    }
    .MuiPickersDay-dayWithMargin {
        margin-top: -15px;
    },
    .MuiPickersDay-dayOutsideMonth{
        margin: 30px;
    }
    .css-i5q14k-MuiDayCalendar-header{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
        `;
return (
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
     <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
         <CustomDateCalendar  
               defaultCalendarMonth={dayjs('2023-06-01')}
               disablePast = {false}
                views={['day']}
                disableFuture = {false}
                maxDate = {dayjs('2023-06-30')}
                minDate = {dayjs('2023-06-12')}
                sx={{
                    marginTop:"85px",
                    marginLeft:"1px",
                    height:"180px",
                    width: "326px",
                    border: "1px solid #EFEFEF",
                    backgroundColor:"white",
                    }}  
                    />
      </ThemeProvider>
 </LocalizationProvider>
)
```

How can I change the size of circled which is colored blue when it clicked?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Calendars = ({state}: {state: StateData;}) => {

  const CustomDateCalendar = styled(DateCalendar)`
    // your styles
  `;

  return (
   <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
     <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
         <CustomDateCalendar  
             // your props
              sx={{
                  // your sx
                  '& .MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected': {
                       bgcolor: 'red !important',
                       width: 40, height: 40,
                  }
              }}  
          />
      </ThemeProvider>
   </LocalizationProvider>
 )
}
```

[image: Edit geocoding-demo (forked)]